# using statement with static class is not working in visual studio 2015 CTP

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, c#-6.0

I have written a following code for one of my C# 6.0 Sample application. It was working fine earlier with Visual Studio 2015 Preview. But now when I have downloaded the newest version of Visual Studio 2015 which launched before some time.(http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2015/01/16/visual-studio-2015-ctp-5-is-available.aspx) it stopped working.

Following is a code for that.

```
using System.Console;

namespace StaticClassUsing
{
     class Program
     {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
              WriteLine("With using statement");
        }
     }
 }
```

Now when you run this application in Latest Version of Visual Studio 2015 its giving error like following.

[image]

I have tried setting up language to C# 6.0. Is Microsoft is moving away with this feature?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you had `using System.Console;` and not `using Console = System.Console;` in your program's source? As far as I know this has never been a language feature.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I have used my examples for my blog - http://www.dotnetjalps.com/2014/12/csharp-6-static-class-using-statement.html and you can find that code on github at following place- https://github.com/dotnetjalps/Csharp6NewFeatures There are few other features also not working

Comment: I haven't seen anything about them removing it, however they do note in the release notes that it is subject to change, and I saw this update note: "The syntax will be more different from current using clauses – it will have the keywords `using static`." [source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/11/20/new-features-in-c-6.aspx)

Comment: That was the feaure of C# 6.0 you can use using statement with static and earlier version of visual studio 2015 it was working fine.

Comment: Works for me with VS 2014 CTP

Comment: @tophallen - can you paste a link for release notes

Comment: here are the release notes - it is also still mentioned, and I checked all later versions and found no mention of it being removed or broken. http://www.visualstudio.com/news/vs2015-preview-vs#ManLang

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This was recently changed from the syntax:

`using System.Console;`

to

`using static System.Console;`

See https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/commit/b49f841bdeeb0b620240d2435f5a0665012f6fce

Comment: Your link doesn't talks about any change of syntax. Am I missing something? Also `using System.Console;` works fine for me in VS 2014 CTP

Comment: In the reference the syntax is `using System.Console`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel see my edit. I linked a relevant commit in the Roslyn repo.

Comment: Interesting!. I can't find any information about this elsewhere :(

Comment: @SriramSakthivel They changed it between CTP releases. Make sure you have the latest one (perhaps download VS2015)

Comment: I have just blogged about it- There is one more changed in string interpolation-http://bit.ly/LatestUpdateCSharp6