# C# cannot find static method inside public method of another class

Tags: c#, methods, static

I have a static class TV:

```
namespace nTV {
    public static class TV {

        public static bool isOn;

        public static void SetOn(){
            //do stuff to set attribute isOn
        }
    }
}
```

and I have the class House:

```
namespace nHouse{
    public class House{

        public void CheckTV(){
            TV.SetOn();
        }

    }
}
```

When I call `TV.SetOn()` (or even `TV.isOn`) from inside House, it says

> *TV* does not contain a definition for *SetOn*.

What am I doing wrong? How can  I find TV's methods inside another class?

Comment: Are you sure the call from CheckTV method uses the correct TV class? I suppose using nTV.TV.SetOn(); doesn't help?

Comment: Call: nTV.TV.SetOn();

Comment: mention namespace: `using nTV;`

Comment: There probably is another `TV` class in the namespace `nHouse` or in a namespace you have included in your `using` statements. Before you add usings or prefix namespaces, you'll have to decide if having two `TV` classes was intentional. (Right-click `TV` and select "Go To Definition")

Comment: It worked, but it seems very strange to me. At first, I included the namespace and it didn't work (just the same error as not including). Why would `nTV.TV.SetOn()` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited**:

I think you have 2 `TV` classes, one in `nHouse` and one in `nTV`.

**Original answer**:

Either as Vulpex suggested, or

add `using nTV;` to the file.

The issue is that the full name of `TV` is `nTV.TV`, but when called from within the same namespace, you can shorten it. So you either

- use the full name
- use it from within the same namespace (obviously not possible here)
- or add a `using` statement as I mentioned.

**EDIT**

<s>It looks like your problem arises from the class being static. You therefore (according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/28123407/939213) need to use the following syntax:</s>

using static nTV;

**EDIT 2**

I've tested my 1st edit solution (using `static`) and seen that a) there is no need for that and b) it doesn't even work (I get an error in Visual Studio). Here is my code which works fine. The files are in separate directories and I put another namespace with a class before each (to test whether that might throw VS off. It didn't.)

```
namespace calledNS
{
    public static class CalledClass
    {
        public static void CalledMethod() { }
    }
}
```

and

```
using calledNS;
...
namespace callerNS
{
    public class CallerClass
    {
        public void CallerMethod() { CalledClass.CalledMethod(); }
    }
}
```

So my only idea (which is actually the most fitting to your errors) is that:

### You have 2 `TV` classes, one in `nHouse` and one in `nTV`.

This would explain all of the behavior you're seeing, I think.

Comment: I tried this but didn't work. It only works when I call the full thing `nTV.TV.SetOn()`. Quite strange, isn't it?

Comment: @Daniel Perhaps rebuilding the project would help?

Comment: @Daniel did `nTV` turn out to be a class, not a namespace? Just curious!

Comment: nTV is the namespace TV is in.

Comment: Thanks for responding - but did `using static nTV` solve your issue? AFAIK that shouldn't work for namespaces, just for types. Odd.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis You need to "at" Daniel for them to get a notification.

Comment: @ispiro Forgot that one then, thanks. Your updated answer would make alot of sense.

Answer (score 2):

Use the full name. You need to tell it from what namespace.

```
namespace nHouse
{
    public class House
    {
        public void CheckTV()
        {
            nTV.TV.SetOn();
        } 
    } 
}
```

OR

```
using nTV;

namespace nHouse
{
    public class House
    {
        public void CheckTV()
        {
            TV.SetOn();
        } 
    } 
}
```

you have to tell the compiler in what namespace to look for the method you're trying to call. Unless you give the fullname `nTV.TV.SetOn()` you will have to name at the beginning of the file to use the namespace with `using nTV;`

[working cs Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ciMct3)

Comment: Although this makes the code compile, it doesn't explain the issue ("What am I doing wrong?").

Comment: @C.Evenhuis  Because you have to name the namespace. It does not know where to look for the `TV.SetOn()` since it is located in a different namespace.

Comment: This really works, but is very strange: as I stated in other comments, writing `using nTV` above nHouse does not allow me to call `TV.SetOn()`, but `nTV.TV.SetOn()` works.

Comment: Are you using different documents ie files or have everything in one file? If you have it all in one file, you have to add the `using nTV` at the top of the file, where all the other `using` statements are. But I could be mistaken and maybe you even have to write the using in the main file for this to work, or both. I've only tested it in one file so far.

Comment: @Vulpex Wouldn't it say "The name 'TV' does not exist in the current context" if it was unable to find that class? Unless I'm missing something, there is _some type or member_ with the name `TV` that it _is_ able to find.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis that depends on the IDE. If you're using vim on linux systems for example, it wouldn't be able to tell.

Comment: @Vulpex So when using vim, if a class is not found, you get _the exact same error_ as when in Visual Studio a _member_ of a class is not found? That's horrible!

Answer (score 1):

The `namespace`s of the classes are *different* (`nTV` and `nHouse`), that's why you should mention `nTV` as `using nTV;`

```
 using nTV;

 ...   

 namespace nHouse {
   public class House{
     public void CheckTV(){
       TV.SetOn();
     }
   }

   ...
 }
```

If you want address `nTV.TV` by its short name `TV`. Another possibility is to declare *both* classes in the *same* namespace:

```
 namespace Houses {
   public static class TV {
     public static bool isOn;

     public static void SetOn(){
       //do stuff to set attribute isOn
     }
   }
 }

 ...

 namespace Houses {
   public class House {
     public void CheckTV() {
       TV.SetOn();
     }
   }
 }
```